# SET A DEFAULT VALUE IN A SELECTOR, ACUMATICA

Tags: acumatica

Need to set warehouse "DTC" as my default warehouse.
any assistance will be highly appreciated

[Image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21wbN.png)

Tried to use the following code to update the warehouse field when inventory id is not null: but got an error
[Image of the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldN4w.png)

protected void AMProdItem_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache,
PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
AMProdItem row = (AMProdItem)e.Row;
if(row != null)return;
row.SiteID= "DTC";
}

Answer (score 0):

Use an additional attribute alongside PXSelector

```
[PXDefault(Search<INSite.siteID, Where<INSite.siteCD, Equal<DTC>>>)]

public class DTC : BqlString.Constant<DTC>
{
    public DTC : base("DTC") { }
}
```

Note, this will not allow you to save a blank in that field, if you want to default without checking for empty use

```
PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing
```

in the PXDefault attribute

Comment: Added this one but it did not work



    #region Siteid
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXDefault("DTC")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Siteid")]
    public virtual int? Siteid { get; set; }
    public abstract class siteid : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<siteid> { }
    #endregion

Comment: Made some edits, didnt realize it was an integer value.

Comment: Also if you want change of InventoryID to trigger the default to run again you can use something like this on your attribute: 
[PXFormula(typeof(Default<AMPRodItem.inventoryID>))]
The attribute goes on the the field with the PXDefault